# Can update function "PasswordSignInAsync" in class "SignInManager" Asp.net MVC5 identity?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, identity

I am new in this field and I need to edit this function body `PasswordSignInAsync` to add extra logic when a user logs in.

For example, I added new column `isActive` to the users table and I want to edit the mentioned function to take this column into consideration while validating user info upon logging in.
If it can be done, I have to edit this enum `SignInStatus` to add the new value `isActive`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit that method... To improve its functionality, you would need to inherit the class in a child class and overload the method.

> OverLoading : Same Function but different signature (i.e return type
>   and parameter types)
>
> EG :
>
> class SillyMath {
>       public static int Plus(int number1, int number2)
>       {
>           return Plus(number1, number2, 0);
>       }
>
> ```
> public static int Plus(int number1, int number2, int number3)
> {
>     return Plus(number1, number2, number3, 0);
> }
>
> public static int Plus(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4)
> {
>     return number1 + number2 + number3 + number4;
> } } Overriding : overriding base class function in child
> ```
>
> EG:
>
> class BaseClass
>       {
>           public virtual  string YourCity()
>           {
>               return "New York";
>           }
>       }
>
> ```
> class DerivedClass : BaseClass
> {
>     public override string YourCity()
>     {
>         return "London";
>     }
> }
>
> class Program
> {
>
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         DerivedClass obj = new DerivedClass();
>         string city = obj.YourCity();
>         Console.WriteLine(city);
>         Console.Read();
>     }
> } Refer : http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/method-overloading/
> ```
>
> http://www.dotnetperls.com/overload
>
> http://www.programcall.com/25/csnet/method-overriding-in-csnet.aspx
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18734/Method-Overriding-in-C
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3(v=vs.71).aspx
>
> http://www.dotnetperls.com/override

source: https://forums.asp.net/t/1851954.aspx

Comment: yes it is. just tested, but i added quotes (from that link) just now.

Comment: thank you dear, actually i know how to override, the problem is i need to write the the same logic exists in the virtual method + the condition i want to add